# How can we pass extra data in lightweight charts series and use in floating tooltip

Tags: reactjs, lightweight-charts

I'm trying to pass some extra key pairs to the lightweight chart series and access that in `subscribeCrosshairMove` event handler.

```
const data = [{
  time: <unix-timestamp>,
  value: <integer>,
  extraData: <string>
}]
const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {});
const series = chart.addLineSeries({ color: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)', lineWidth: 3 });
series.setData(data)
chart.subscribeCrosshairMove(function(param) {
   // Here I want to access that extraData key
   // param only contains value and time keys, not extraData.
});
```

Could anyone please let me know how can I achieve this? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `time` property to find the desired data point in the original data set.

```js
chart.subscribeCrosshairMove((param) => {
   const datapoint = data.find(point => point.time === param.time);
   console.log(datapoint.extraData);
});
```

However, it would be slow to search through the data array each time so it would be beneficial to store the `extraData` values in a map/object for easier retrieval.

```js
series.setData(data);

const extraData = new Map();
data.forEach(datapoint => {
    extraData.set(datapoint.time, datapoint.extraData);
});

chart.subscribeCrosshairMove((param) => {
   console.log(extraData.get(param.time));
});
```

Comment: I've more than one series in my graph and can have more than one data point simultaneously. In that case, how can I get the extraData from hovered series not any other? because I'm always getting `undefined` in `param.hoveredseries`.

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem `hoveredSeries` will return `undefined` unless you are hovering over a seriesMarker. The name is confusing, and will be potentially changed. You can track that progress here: https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/944

... If you have more than one series then you could use the `value` property to determine which series is the closest and then retrieve the extra data from that series.

Comment: @SlicedSilver Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some unique field for example `age` in every item of your `initialArray`, and you want to display it in tooltip, like `time` and `value`, you can do something like this:
Create a ref of an object with shape:

```
type Ages = {
  [key: number]: number;
};
```

```
const agesRef = useRef<Ages | null>(null)
```

Next, in useEffect where you initializing your chart do this:

```
agesRef.current = initialArray.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [index + 1]: item.age,
  };
}, {});
```

```
  // update tooltip position
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!chartContainerRef.current) return;

    const moveHandler = (param: MouseEventParams) => {  
      const age = agesRef.current?.[(param.logical as number)];
      console.log(age)
      // Pass your age to tooltip's state or where you need
    };

    chartRef.current?.subscribeCrosshairMove(moveHandler);

    return () => {
      chartRef.current?.unsubscribeCrosshairMove(moveHandler);
    };
  }, []);
```

Looking for a property in object by key is much faster than filter or mapping through the whole array and looking for a match